# Why does "Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "okular"" take a relatively long time?

Tags: snap

Xubuntu 20.04 (in a VM)

I've installed `ksnip` as a snap but I noticed that

> Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "ksnip"

took a long time (5-10 min) after `ksnip` was downloaded.

Installing `okular` as a snap took even longer (after `okular` itself was downloaded).

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           394M  1.2M  393M   1% /run
/dev/sda5        20G  6.2G   12G  35% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  4.0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           394M   16K  394M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0       28M   28M     0 100% /snap/snapd/7264
/dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop2      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/ksnip/3
/dev/loop3       63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop4      261M  261M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
/dev/loop5       20M   20M     0 100% /snap/okular/98
/dev/loop6      291M  291M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4
$
```

So what is happening during this process? Is it normally time-consuming?

Is it that the other "supporting" snaps were being downloaded with the less-than-meaningful (to me) "Automatically connect eligible plugs …" nessage? `ksnip` is a qt-based program and pulled in `/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32`. And `okular`, also a qt-based program, pulled in `/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4` both of which are much, much larger than `ksnip` and `okular`. In which case, the delay would just be a network issue?

Answer (score 19):

It seems that

> Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "..."

is just a way to indicate that supplementary material is being downloaded.

While the downloading of `okular` has a straightforward progress indicator, the time while "Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "..."" is in progress is denoted by just a rotating `|`.

However, if one keeps Ubuntu's system monitor open at the same time, it's quite evident that "Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots ..." means a download is in progress.

The process in the terminal and the downloading activity shown in the system conclude at the same time.

In the case of installing the `okular` snap on a clean (no other `qt`-dependent snap having been installed) Ubuntu 20.04, the supplementary material downloaded *after* the `okular` snap is `kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18  5.68.0`. Watching the network activity in the system monitor indicates that approximately 333 MiB were downloaded.

It's not a big deal but now I know that "Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots ..." means downloading stuff.